# Scrapy - issues with crawling deeper into the website

Tags: python, scrapy

The website I am trying to crawl has the following structure:

- there are various modules (for which I generate links without issues) - let's call them "module_urls"
- each module page has a random number of links to various pages with videos (let's call them "lesson_urls")
- each page has one video

The idea is to print links to all videos.

I have successfully managed to, separately: (1) generate the module_urls, (2) scrape the links to lesson_urls, and (3) scrape the videos. However, I am struggling with creating the appropriate loop to make it all work together.

The following script correctly generates module_urls, but, contrary to my expectations, the request to crawl each url (and then to crawl each sub-url) is never fulfilled. I am sure that this comes from my pure ignorance of the topic - this is the first time I am trying to use Scrapy.

Thank you very much for your help!

```
video_links = []
def after_login(self, response):
    module_urls = self.generate_links()
    for module_url in module_urls:
        print("This is one module URL: %s" % module_url)
        Request(module_url, self.get_lesson_urls)
    print(self.video_links)

def get_lesson_urls(self, response):
    print("Entered get_lesson_urls")
    urls = response.xpath('//*[starts-with(@id,"post")]//li/a/@href').extract()
    for lesson_url in urls:
        Request(lesson_url, self.get_video_link)

def get_video_link(self, response):
    video_address = response.xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "post")]//iframe[@name = "vooplayerframe"]/@src').extract_first()
    self.video_links.append(video_address)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will need to yield your request objects

```
video_links = []
def after_login(self, response):
    module_urls = self.generate_links()
    for module_url in module_urls:
        print("This is one module URL: %s" % module_url)
        yield Request(module_url, self.get_lesson_urls)

def get_lesson_urls(self, response):
    print("Entered get_lesson_urls")
    urls = response.xpath('//*[starts-with(@id,"post")]//li/a/@href').extract()
    for lesson_url in urls:
        yield Request(lesson_url, self.get_video_link)

def get_video_link(self, response):
    video_address = response.xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "post")]//iframe[@name = "vooplayerframe"]/@src').extract_first()
    yield video_address
```

Edit:
Rather than print, if you then yield the urls you want, you can output them to json (and other formats) using:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -o data.json
```

You can do further parsing with Scrapy's Item Pipeline: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

Comment: I have just come to the same conclusion, having read more examples online - thank you for confirming! However, how can I perform print(video_links)? I would like to output all the video links gathered after the crawling is completed...

Comment: That's so much simpler than I expected! It just outputs all the items found, no need to play with appending them to some dictionary, writing the code to save to the file etc.... beautiful.